# Adding onClick to RecyclerView after parsing JSON data

Tags: javascript, android, json

I have a fragment in which reside a RecyclerView. I parsed JSON data from a webpage and showed it in this RecyclerView using tutorial: https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/02/recyclerview-json-parsing.html

Now I wish to add an onClick to the RecyclerView items. I know how to do so for static RecyclerView items but don't know to setOnClickListener in this case. For static recyclerview items, I'm using this class for onClick events.

```
package com.parassidhu.cdlumaths;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;

public class ItemClickSupport {
    private final RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;
    private OnItemLongClickListener mOnItemLongClickListener;
    private View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
                RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = mRecyclerView.getChildViewHolder(v);
                mOnItemClickListener.onItemClicked(mRecyclerView, holder.getAdapterPosition(), v);
            }
        }
    };
    private View.OnLongClickListener mOnLongClickListener = new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            if (mOnItemLongClickListener != null) {
                RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = mRecyclerView.getChildViewHolder(v);
                return mOnItemLongClickListener.onItemLongClicked(mRecyclerView, holder.getAdapterPosition(), v);
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
    private RecyclerView.OnChildAttachStateChangeListener mAttachListener
            = new RecyclerView.OnChildAttachStateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildViewAttachedToWindow(View view) {
            if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
                view.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
            }
            if (mOnItemLongClickListener != null) {
                view.setOnLongClickListener(mOnLongClickListener);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildViewDetachedFromWindow(View view) {

        }
    };

    private ItemClickSupport(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
        mRecyclerView.setTag(R.id.item_click_support, this);
        mRecyclerView.addOnChildAttachStateChangeListener(mAttachListener);
    }

    public static ItemClickSupport addTo(RecyclerView view) {
        ItemClickSupport support = (ItemClickSupport) view.getTag(R.id.item_click_support);
        if (support == null) {
            support = new ItemClickSupport(view);
        }
        return support;
    }

    public static ItemClickSupport removeFrom(RecyclerView view) {
        ItemClickSupport support = (ItemClickSupport) view.getTag(R.id.item_click_support);
        if (support != null) {
            support.detach(view);
        }
        return support;
    }

    public ItemClickSupport setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mOnItemClickListener = listener;
        return this;
    }

    public ItemClickSupport setOnItemLongClickListener(OnItemLongClickListener listener) {
        mOnItemLongClickListener = listener;
        return this;
    }

    private void detach(RecyclerView view) {
        view.removeOnChildAttachStateChangeListener(mAttachListener);
        view.setTag(R.id.item_click_support, null);
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {

        void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v);
    }

    public interface OnItemLongClickListener {

        boolean onItemLongClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v);
    }
}
```

My Adapter Class is:

```
package com.parassidhu.cdlumaths;

import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.parassidhu.cdlumaths.R;
import com.parassidhu.cdlumaths.Android;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NoticesData extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NoticesData.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Android> mAndroidList;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public NoticesData(ArrayList<Android> androidList, RecyclerView rcl) {
        mAndroidList = androidList;
        recyclerView=rcl;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.notices_row, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mTvName.setText(mAndroidList.get(position).getName());
        ItemClickSupport.addTo(recyclerView).setOnItemClickListener(new ItemClickSupport.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v) {
            //I can't call Toast or startIntent here
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mAndroidList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private TextView mTvName;
        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mTvName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the code to your adapter class ?

Comment: Will post in few hrs

Comment: @Superman I have added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Activity or Fragment class create a method like below

```
public void showToast(int position) {
  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked position is " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

(I think you're using Fragment so I used `getActivity()`)

Now update your Adapter constructor like this

```
...
...
private YourFragment frag;

public NoticesData(ArrayList<Android> androidList, RecyclerView rcl, YourFragment fragment) {
    mAndroidList = androidList;
    recyclerView = rcl;
    frag = fragment;
}
```

In your Fragment update Adapter initialization like this

```
NoticesData notice = NoticesData(androidList, rcl, YourFragment.this);
```

Now call the `showToast()` method like below in Adapter

```
ItemClickSupport.addTo(recyclerView).setOnItemClickListener(new ItemClickSupport.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v) {

           frag.showToast(position);  // it's like callback method

        }
    });
```

Note: here YourFragment means the Fragment which hosts your RecyclerView.

Comment: Thankssss! It worked like a charm. Just what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

you must set click listener for each of the items in your recycler view from the adapter for that recycler view. when you set the data for each if the items (views) in the recycler view you can add the onClickListener for that view too.

Comment: I'm able to add the onClickListener from adapter class but I can't do some actions in adapter class for example I can't startIntent or show Toast. Should i do something different?